# Is there a way to have links to the revisions in the `changes` package?

Tags: hyperref, packages, changes

The `changes` package is great for highlighting additions, deletions and revisions when editing documents, and it generates a handly list of all your changes. Does anyone know if there's a way to have that list generate links to the changes, maybe using `hyperref`, so that a reviewer could click on a change in the listing and be taken to its place in the document?

Comment: Just including `\usepackage{hyperref}` is sufficient for this, entries in the list of changes will be automatically linked to the corresponding change item in the text.

Comment: @Marijn Hmm, it's not working for me. Does the import order matter? Might other packages be messing with hyperref here?

Comment: the order does not seem to matter, for me it works with `hyperref` first and `changes` second and vice versa. Maybe you have an old version (I use TeX Live 2017). To find the cause of the problem, you should make a minimal (non)working example consisting of a documentclass, the two packages, some changes, maybe some text in between, and then the list of changes. If that doesn't work, then post it here as part of your question. If that does work, then start adding packages from your real document until it stops working and then post it here.

Comment: I am on the problem, please see <https://gitlab.com/ekleinod/changes/-/issues/77> for the current status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality was introduced in v4.1.0 of the package. Just update the package via your distro and it should work.
(as @marijn said, you have to use `\usepackage{hyperref}`)