# List of changes - create hyperlinks

Tags: hyperlink, changes

My question is strongly related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490843/is-there-a-way-to-have-links-to-the-revisions-in-the-changes-package) but the comments don't work for me.
I want the entries in the list of changes to be automatically linked to the corresponding change item in the text. But it doesn't work..

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[commentmarkup=uwave]{changes}

\begin{document}

\listofchanges
\newpage

This is a test \comment{Bla}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see any support for links in the current version of package and it doesn't use \addcontentsline, so hyperref can do nothing. You will have to make a feature request.

Comment: Just found out that there is already a feature request [here](https://gitlab.com/ekleinod/changes/-/issues/77) - hope somebody finds a nice solution

Comment: I wrote the comment in the related post from May 2019, I just checked the test pdf I compiled back then (which I still have) and it has links. However, when I compile the exact same file now it does not have links. And the issue #77 was started in December 2019, eight months after my comment, so I don't understand what is going on exactly :)

Comment: @Marijn I assume the author improved his code ...

Comment: I added a comment to the feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just uploaded v4.1.0 to CTAN, this version makes the list of changes clickable.

So the answer is: wait a few days, then update your distro or install the style file yourself:

https://gitlab.com/ekleinod/changes/-/releases/4.1.0